# Appendix is ​not justified

Tags: horizontal-alignment, appendices, appendix

For some reason, the appendix is ​​not justified. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. This is my code:

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
%\pagestyle{headings}
%\rhead{\thepage}
%\section*{CHAPTER 3}
\appendix
\hspace{1,5cm}
\section{APPENDIX}
\indent
\subsection{WKB METHOD}
}
```

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. We don't know which document class you are using, nor a sample preamble. So instead of this sniplet please post something self contained that shows your problem

Comment: Additionally what is that `} ` at the end ending? That hspace also seems out of place